# Why is Mathematica taking so long to solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I was trying to solve a polarization problem where I needed to solve this transcendental equation.

```
NSolve[(Cos[\[Pi]/n])^(2 n) == 0.90, n]
```

I don't know why but Mathematica is taking a very long time trying to solve it while Desmos gives the answer instantly. What should I do to speed it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you give a range for `n` `NSolve` evaluates all solutions immediately:

```
NSolve[{(Cos[\[Pi]/n])^(2 n) == 0.90, 0 < n < 1}, n, Reals]
```

`{{n -> 0.000444741}, {n -> 0.000460511}, {n -> 0.00134138}, {n ->  0.00169924}, {n -> 0.00223964}, {n -> 0.00294551}, {n ->  0.00330579}, {n -> 0.00391389}, {n -> 0.004158}, {n ->  0.00468384}, {n -> 0.00519481}, {n -> 0.0056338}, {n ->  0.00573066}, {n -> 0.00677965}, {n -> 0.00754719}, {n ->  0.0079681}, {n -> 0.0081633}, {n -> 0.00947856}, {n ->  0.00995041}, {n -> 0.0102562}, {n -> 0.0112998}, {n ->  0.0114282}, {n -> 0.0130729}, {n -> 0.013244}, {n ->  0.0146004}, {n -> 0.0152648}, {n -> 0.016003}, {n ->  0.0162569}, {n -> 0.0165325}, {n -> 0.0168028}, {n ->  0.0173867}, {n -> 0.0177042}, {n -> 0.0180125}, {n ->  0.0183547}, {n -> 0.018685}, {n -> 0.0190549}, {n ->  0.0194095}, {n -> 0.0198107}, {n -> 0.0201925}, {n ->  0.0206291}, {n -> 0.0210411}, {n -> 0.0215181}, {n ->  0.021964}, {n -> 0.0224874}, {n -> 0.0229715}, {n ->  0.0235483}, {n -> 0.0240756}, {n -> 0.0247145}, {n ->  0.025291}, {n -> 0.0260025}, {n -> 0.0266353}, {n ->  0.0274324}, {n -> 0.0281301}, {n -> 0.0290293}, {n ->  0.0298022}, {n -> 0.0308242}, {n -> 0.0316849}, {n ->  0.0328564}, {n -> 0.0338209}, {n -> 0.0351763}, {n ->  0.0362645}, {n -> 0.0378501}, {n -> 0.0390874}, {n ->  0.0409654}, {n -> 0.0423851}, {n -> 0.0446417}, {n ->  0.0462881}, {n -> 0.049046}, {n -> 0.0509793}, {n ->  0.0544189}, {n -> 0.0567238}, {n -> 0.0611202}, {n ->  0.0639201}, {n -> 0.0697138}, {n -> 0.0731964}, {n ->  0.0811357}, {n -> 0.0856037}, {n -> 0.0970629}, {n ->  0.103043}, {n -> 0.120829}, {n -> 0.129337}, {n -> 0.160146}, {n -> 0.173482}, {n -> 0.237862}, {n -> 0.262804}, {n ->  0.465417}, {n -> 0.53725}}`

Comment: Nice. There is one more solution at `n == 93.6922` you can get with `NSolve[{(Cos[\[Pi]/n])^(2 n)==0.90,n>1},n,Reals]`. It looks like there are none for `n<0`

Comment: Thanks for your hint.  Probably there are more solutions near `n->0`

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is all solutions. If you do, e.g., `0 < n < 0.1` you get even more solutions. There's  probably an infinite number of them.

Comment: Indeed, `LogLinearPlot[Cos[\[Pi]/x]^(2 x), {x, 0, 10}]` shows that there is an infinite number of solutions, which shouldn't be surprising, as Cos[π/x] has an essential singularity.

Answer (score 4):

Re Ulrich's comment that there are probably more solutions as `n` approaches zero.

```
Length[sol = Join[
   NSolve[{(Cos[π/n])^(2 n) == 9/10, 0 <= n <= 1}, n, Reals, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 40],
   NSolve[{(Cos[π/n])^(2 n) == 9/10, n > 1}, n, Reals, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 40]]]

(* 86 *)

({min, max} = MinMax[sol[[All, 1, -1]]]) // N

(* {0.00134138, 93.6922} *)
```

Looking in the region `{0, min}`

```
Length[sol2 = 
  NSolve[{(Cos[π/n])^(2 n) == 9/10, 0 <= n <= min}, n, Reals, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 40]]

(* 967 *)

({min2, max2} = MinMax[sol2[[All, 1, -1]]]) // N

(* {2.40645*10^-6, 0.00134138} *)
```

Zooming in again,

```
Length[sol3 = 
  NSolve[{(Cos[π/n])^(2 n) == 9/10, 0 <= n <= min2}, n, Reals, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 40]]

(* 831 *)
```

and so on ...